# Using GoogleSheets is there a way to extract text thats always moving from cell to cell?

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to set up automatic upload to my e-comm site but I'm struggling with the CSV I've been given. Is there a way to extract the Brand result no matter where it would be?

Cell 1 Example
Brands>***RESULT***|Data1>Data2

Cell 2 Example
Data1>Data2|Brands>***RESULT***

Cell 3 Example
Data1>Data2|Brands>***RESULT***|Data3>Data4

Comment: Sorry i didn't clarify, I'm trying to make a Regular Expression to extract the Brand

Comment: Each of those texts are in a cell of their own? Or do the `|` represent a column separation?